# FLTK popup window inside main window

Tags: user-interface, fltk

I wonder how can I pop up a window within the main window, that is, the child window can be moved freely only inside the main window. I want something like Photoshop interface: You can open several images inside the main window. When minimizing, their title bars aligned well at the bottom of the border of the main window. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the FLTK Dock project - http://fltkdock.sourceforge.net . That is the only one (that I know of) that offers something similar to what you ask. FLTK Dock is a dead project, nothing new since 2006, which is a pitty - I liked it a lot. It should not be difficult to port to FLTK 3.0 though.

Comment: Yeah, it is something close to dock widget in Qt. But Qt is a monster. Thank you very much.